# Appian WebAPI Authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, webapi, datastore, appian

OAuth2.0 in webapi

Aim is to implement Web APIs authenticated by an OAuth 2.0 client in appian.

1.I have created a sample WebAPI.

2. I have created a OAuth credentials from adminconsole.  AdminConsole->Web API Authentication->OAuthclients2.0
   [image: AuthenticationCreated image]

If i try to access the webapi from browser it is accessible without authorisation. How to integrate this OAuth with my API. is there any attribute needs to be added in appian webapi.?

Kindly help.

How to apply oauth authentication with appian webapi?

Comment: Asking this question on appian community will be a better option as Appian engineers are active only at that portal.

Answer (score 1):

All the WebAPIs in Appian are already secured with Authorization. There is no additional step needed.

The reason you are able to access it without OAuth is probably because, in the browser, you are already logged in with your own account.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is add the service account on which you created the Oauth credentials to the application groups in appian application designer